# Access 2010: How to Handle Compund Primary Keys in Datasheets and Forms

Tags: ms-access-2010, compound-key

I am trying to design a database to ease with my grading process.  I want to add assignments to the database, add questions to each assignment, and weight the questions as percentages of the whole.  Students commonly make the same mistakes, so I want to be able to also track reasons for docking credit for each question and the amount docked so I can simply link that student's assignment submission to the mistakes they made.  The goal is to be able to grade students equally with a single query, which gives a student a zero if they did not submit and a grade accounting for all the deductions earned if they did.

I have designed the table structure as shown in the picture below:

[image: Current relationship structure for described database]

The tool I have available to me is Access 2010 (with which the above relationship diagram was made).  I am trying to step beyond describing tables to building forms to help me populate them.  The problem is that, as a beginner, I cannot figure out how to get Access to work with the compound primary keys.  I cannot figure out how to get any sort of form to link to multiple fields, or how to get multiple inputs to link to each other so I can set up decent drop-down lists for combo boxes, or even how to get the data sheet views for the tables to use combo boxes to make these foreign keys work.

At this point, I can only see two options: changing these tables with compound primary keys to have different fields for primary keys and setting compound unique constraints on the current primary keys (which I have no idea how to do in Access 2010), or giving up on the whole idea and switching back to laboriously attempting everything in Excel.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I could:

- easily change the table structure to make forms work cleanly and easily for data entry and manipulation?
- get the forms and datasheets to work with the current compound key paradigm?

Comment: To me, the easiest option would be to add autonumber keys to the various tables and change the compound primary keys to unique constraints. This will considerably speed up form design.

Comment: BTW datasheets offer much less control than single and continuous forms.

Comment: I think that might be the best way, too.  How do I set up a compound unique constraint so that duplicate values are allowed in any single field, but duplicate values in tuples of fields are not allowed?

Comment: Open the table in design view, choose the Indexes button from the ribbon and look at the current set up. You can reproduce it with a different name and set the Primary property to No.

Comment: The only thing I can see enforcing that each tuple of values be unique is the primary key status.  As for copying the values, they currently aren't working as I'd like, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an image of what I am suggesting, the primary key contents are copied to a new key. The primary key can then be deleted.

[image]

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, the way to set up a compound unique constraint is to (1) open the Indices dialog for the table, (2) name a new index and add multiple fields to it on sequential rows, and (3) set the Unique property to Yes?

Comment: My experiments show that this approach works.  Thanks!  Rewrite the post to be more tutorial and I'll give this an upvote, too :)